# random user load on visual studio load test

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a requirement where we want to test a large amount of users doing a single operation with in a specified duration. So for example 1000 users logging on with in 10 minutes, but randomly. So i would need to generate 1000 users doing one iteration for a test and then stopping.

Is it possible to generate this type of load using visual studio load test  ?

Answer (score 0):

for those interested, i was able to accomplish this using custom load profiler mentioned here http://blogs.msdn.com/slumley/pages/creating-a-custom-load-profile-which-will-step-user-load-up-and-then-back-down.aspx